# I am stuck while converting from local (US/ Central) time zone to UTC. I cannot see any change in the time zone after using tz_convert?

Tags: python, pandas

So before making any changes to the code it is looking something like this :

input:

```
df_welldata['firstProductionDate']
```

output:

```
1995-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

So I did something like this:

```
df_welldata.firstProductionDate = pd.to_datetime(df_welldata['firstProductionDate'])
df_welldata.firstProductionDate = df_welldata['firstProductionDate'].dt.tz_convert(pytz.utc)
```

and after this my output is looking something like this :

```
1995-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

It looks like the format has been changed but the number of hours should be changed as well but that is not happening. Could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is your expected result? The original data does not seem to have any time zone information.

Comment: I want the output to be in UTC time zone and currently it is in US/ Central time zone.

Comment: "Z" after the time is denoting the time is in UTC (Zero offset).  so your original timestamp is UTC time and not local time.

Comment: Thank you @Emma. I am new to this so I didn't know. So just to confirm the displayed output is correct, right?

Comment: Sure.  the output looks good to me. In fact, you probably don't need the 2nd line.  `pd.to_datetime(df_welldata['firstProductionDate'])` should be already converting the time with UTC timezone info.  Check the result after this line if you are getting the same result as your current result.

Comment: here is the ref about the datetime format with Z suffix.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)